# How to delete large amount of log files by date (Specifically year)

Tags: linux, files, logs, date, rm

Wondering how I delete large amount of log files that are ordered by date.

Consider the example of having a retention rate of 2 years in a company, how would I go about efficiently and safely deleting files in that directory older than a year (Or two for that matter)

Comment: use [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)

Comment: How would you tell the age of a file? Is it encoded in its name? By the timestamps on each line? By the ctime or mtime of the file? If this is a homework or quiz question, please give us the entire text and tell us what you've tried so far.

Comment: ls -thrl brings it up, not necessarily in the filename itself.

Answer (score 1):

Based on file modification time, I would use merely use find command (here for files older than 1 year):

```
find <mydir-path>/ -mtime +365 -exec rm -fv {} \;
```

Comment: consider also `-type f` and `-delete` (given the Linux tag, it's safe to assume they have GNU find)